# Optional[Type[Foo]] raises TypeError in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, python-3.5, typing

This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from typing import Optional, Type

class Foo(object):
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

def test_me() -> Optional[Type[Foo]]:
    print("Hi there!")
    return Bar

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_me()
```

will raise `TypeError` on 3.5.2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 11, in <module>
    def test_me() -> Optional[Type[Foo]]:
  File "/Users/mnot/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 649, in __getitem__
return Union[arg, type(None)]
  File "/Users/mnot/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "/Users/mnot/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/Users/mnot/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/Users/mnot/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 1077, in __subclasscheck__
if super().__subclasscheck__(cls):
  File "/Users/mnot/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/abc.py", line 225, in __subclasscheck__
for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

whereas it runs fine on 3.6. Same problem if I spell out Optional as `Union[None, Type[Foo]]`.

Is there any workaround for 3.5.2, while still accurately annotating the return type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/266) in Python 3.5.2.

`Optional[cls]` is a wrapper for `Union[cls, type(None)]`, which uses `__subclasses__()` to establish whether one class is a subclass of another.

However, `Type` is a subclass of `type` in Python 3.5.2, which means that

```
Union[Type[anything], anything_else]
```

will eventually call

```
type.__subclasses__()
```

… which is a problem, because `type` is a metaclass, and so expects to be called with the class whose subclasses are being sought, in exactly the same way that calling an instance method on a regular class requires you to supply an instance of itself, e.g. `str.upper('foo')`.

The problem is [fixed](https://github.com/python/typing/commit/a1952c4a0a21b14887bd536fc494d15516667b37#diff-15eca194f829b962c9d102b4ac8ab378L1608) in Python 3.5.3 (and, as you've noticed, 3.6) by making `Type` no longer a subclass of `type`.

Answer (score 0):

Thx Zero Piraeus

i had same problem i ve using python 3.5.2 
i ve edit 
usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py file

```
class Type(type, Generic[CT_co], extra=type):
```

CHANGED TO

```
class Type(Generic[CT_co], extra=type):
```

then it fixed ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue on python 3.5.2

I just installed the lower version of pandas

```
pandas==0.24.2
```

Default installed version was

```
pandas==0.25.1
```

Hope this help.